# install keras: namespace 'Rcpp' and lazy loading failed for package 'reticulate'

Tags: r, keras

I would install keras but i get these errors

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'Rcpp' 0.12.4 is being loaded, but >= 0.12.7 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'reticulate'
* removing 'C:/Anaconda3/R/library/reticulate'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I update package Rcpp with these commands, it does not solve anything

```
install.packages("Rcpp")
install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE)
```

I delete Rcpp in R/library and reinstall it and I still have the same problem

Comment: Try deleting Anaconda and install everything (without Anaconda this time).

Comment: Hello, thank for your help.